# Entity Framework 6 with Automapper Linked Property Add Problem

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-6, automapper

I am using entity framework to add entity to database but it throws an error called can not add same record. Here is an example:

```
public class User : CodeBasedEntity, IUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserGroup")]
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup : CodeBasedEntity, IUserGroup
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; } = false;
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();

}
```

Those are domain classes, there are DTO classes below:

```
public class UserDTO : CodeBasedDTO, IUserDTO
{
    private string _password;
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Şifre boş geçilemez!")]
    [MaxLength(254)]
    [DataMember]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _password)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                _password = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Kullanıcı Grubu")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı Grubu boş geçilemez!")]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual UserGroupDTO UserGroup { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroupDTO : CodeBasedDTO, IUserGroupDTO
{
    public UserGroupDTO()
    {
        Users = new List<UserDTO>();
    }

    private bool _isAdmin = false;
    [DataMember]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public bool IsAdmin
    {
        get { return _isAdmin; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isAdmin)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                _isAdmin = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In a WCF service I am trying to add User but it throws an error that I can not add same UserGroup to database, but it is linked property on User. I don't want to add new UserGroup, what I'm trying is using existing UserGroup as a foreign key in my User table. Here is WcfService code:

```
public abstract class CodeBasedService<Repository, Entity, DTO> : Service<Repository, Entity, DTO>, ICodeBasedService<DTO>
    where Repository : ICodeBasedRepository<Entity>
    where Entity : class
    where DTO : CodeBasedDTO
{

    public override DTO Add(DTO dto)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork worker = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var property = worker.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(Repository).Name).GetValue(worker);
            dto.Code = GenerateCode(dto);
            var entity = Utils.Mapper.Map<DTO, Entity>(dto);
            property.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(property, new object[] { entity });
            worker.SaveChanges();
            var numbering = worker.NumberingRepository.GetByCode(entity.GetType().Name);
            numbering.LastNumber += 1;
            worker.NumberingRepository.Update(numbering);
            worker.SaveChanges();
            return Utils.Mapper.Map<DTO>(entity);
        }
    }

    public string GenerateCode(DTO dto)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork worker = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var property = worker.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(Repository).Name).GetValue(worker);
            return (string)property.GetType().GetMethod("GenerateCode").Invoke(property, new object[] { Utils.Mapper.Map<Entity>(dto) });
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please lead me to solve this problem? I think it is about Automapper.

Comment: I suspect the problem will be solved if you *remove* the generic repository, custom UnitOfWork and probably Automapper too. "Generic" repositories are an *anti*pattern when used on top of higher-level abstractions like ORMs, especially EF. In EF, the DbSet is a repository already, the DbContext is a Unit-of-Work. A DbContext *already* caches all changes and only persists them *in a batch* when you call `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I suspect this `UnitOfWork` actually wraps a database transaction, thus breaking another  ORM feature, disconnected operations. If EF was used properly, if there were no intermediate calls to `SaveChanges`, there wouldn't be a need for an extra database transaction

Comment: To troubleshoot your specific error you should post the full exception text. What you described doesn't sound like an AutoMapper exception. In the meantime check Oren Eini's [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) - the article is from 2009, which shows how well-known the problem is. Also Gunnar Peipman's [You don't need Repository and Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) which explains why the current code could do 5 DELETEs for a single `Add`

Comment: I am trying to add a user has a user group on db, the inner exception message is "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserGroups' with unique index 'IX_Code'. The duplicate key value is (USG0001).
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you tried to insert a record with a PK that already existed. It also shows that instead of using an auto incremented ID as a primary key, a composite with business meaning was used, a very bad idea.  The code doesn't show *any* of that though - no EF Code, lots of reflection. It's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: With db-generated keys, EF will handle adding or updating detached entities automatically with `AddOrUpdate` by checking the ID value. If it's 0, it means it's a new entity that doesn't have an ID yet. If it's >0, it's an existing record that should be updated, not inserted. In EF Core this is replaced by a single call to `Update`

Comment: Is `worker.NumberingRepository.GetByCode(` the code that generates the ID? Unless it uses a SEQUENCE in the database, it will produce duplicate entries if multiple threads/requests call it at the same time. That's why such operations should be left to the database, using `DEFAULT` constraints for example. `DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR My_Sequence)` will always create incrementing key values from the `My_Sequence` sequence

Comment: Here is the example, I created a new UserDto instance, I gave Code, Name and Password properties. Then, from UserGorups I choose USG0001 UserGroup from database. I sent the dto to WCF service, automapper maps UserDTO to User class. When I say add User to db context, it throws the error that I can not add this UserGorup because it is already in the database.

Comment: But you have no idea what the code you posted does. Clearly it tries to store the same ID twice. But all this reflection and code hide what's actually going on for **no** benefit. If that `"Add"` eventually calls `DbContext.Add` you'll be inserting users even if they need updating. If those users are always new objects, the problem is in the key generation code

Comment: The UserGorupId is 1 not 0 but I did not understand the exact issue. DbContext did not recognize as an existing record, it tries to add a new one.

Comment: **Remove** all this code and just use EF directly. That's the only way you'll be able to understand what is going on. What the error says is that your code tried to insert a *new group*, even though you sent a user only. That's because your User DTO also contained a UserGroup. Your code used `Add` so EF assumed you wanted to insert that too

Comment: I will try just using Repository, Data and Core layers, and will inform you. That way we can decide the problem is related with Service layer or not.

Comment: *Don't* use Repository at all. It offers nothing. I already posted links to articles that explain what the problem is. Besides - wasn't that your repository code?? The *service* layer is your actual WCF service code, offering the business functionality users need. If that functionality is too complex you may need to split it to different layers, but splitting is *not* meant to be used without reason

Comment: Start with a *simple* services - just the WCF operations, each with code doing what it needs to be done. Don't try to solve future problems - why would you need a "Repository" or "Data" layer to abstract storage when you already have an ORM that does that for you? And could store to SQLite just as easily as Oracle or MySQL? Don't add complexity until you actually need it

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, I tried to use the layer I mentioned above, it works like a charm. I am little bit confused why service layer and auto-mapper change the original working way. Can you please help me about a solution using entity framework and wcf layers? How I will interact with them?

Comment: Using EF in WCF may cause serialization problems, you can refer to this link, in the link I explained how to use EF in WCF:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910361/how-to-access-ef-navigation-properties-via-wcf-soap-service/61932072#61932072

Comment: Hi Ding, I set this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; in DbContext, but nothing changes :(

Comment: Does the added record already exist in the database? It is recommended that you determine whether this record already exists when adding the record to the database.

Comment: There is a new user that has UserGroup property is an existing data in database. When I try to add the user, it throws an error that the user group already exists.

Comment: I figured it out last night. The property UserGorup is coming from another instance of DB context. Probably the error comes from that but if I share the same DB context instance between repositories, I could not find the records added after DB context initializing time. DbContext is like an image of db when initialized, if you use another forms to add another entities, you can not reach them in existing context.

Comment: @GökmenEskin `if I share the same DB context instance between repositories` there's your bug then. A DbContext is a UoW, not a connection or an image of the DB at all - whether that means an up-to-date clone of the data (it's not, it's meant to work disconnected) or as a model of the database (it's only meant to handle a single use case/DDD bounded context). So your framework doesn't work as well as you thought